# List Product filtered by attributes

Tags: magento-1.9

Add a brand attribute.Add a custom page and show all the  brand values. On clicking the brand values display the products filtered by the selected value.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest and lazy:

You could add a logo on the `view.phtml` with the specific attribute(add files to your skin or media for example `skin/frontend/package/default/gfx/brands/mybrand.jpg`)

Make the attribute searchable and add a link to the image which fills in the brand in the searchfield like `catalogsearch/result/?q=mybrand`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a brand attribute make it filterable on your product catalog page then create an attribute for brand or use the existing "Manufacture" one and under Properities >> Front End Properties >> Used In Layered Navigation >> select Filterable with Results. This may also depend on your theme.

IF you want to make a page that will list all your brands and once you click on a brand, it will take you to a page with filtered products by that brand. You need to create a custom page and put in some code that will call the particular brand and list the products. For me right now, I just do this by editing the url link. For example: adding "?manufacturer=37 to the end of a link and it appears the products for that "brand" however this is per category only.